# Vector space over field $F$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is the group $\def\R{\Bbb R}V=\{\,(x,y) \in \R^{2}\mid y=2x\,\}$ a vector space over $F=\R$, with the regular addition in $\R^2$ and the Scalar multiplication operation $\otimes: F\times V\to V$ defined by $\lambda \otimes (x,y)=(\lambda x,0)$?

Comment: Note: your field is (supposedly) just $\R$ with its usual operations; one gains nothing by calling it $F$. The only thing unusual are the "vector space" operations, not the field $F$.

Answer (score 1):

It is not even closed under multiplication, for example:

$$3\otimes(1,2):=(3,0)\notin V\;\;\text{since}\;\;0\neq2\cdot3$$

Answer (score 1):

One of the vector space axioms is that multiplication by the scalar$~1$ fixes every vector; that clearly fails here for any pair of reals with nonzero second component. Since $V$ contains such elements, is is not a vector space for these operations.